# Set Logitech F310 gamepad in qjoypad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, games, logitech, gamepad

I have installed `qjoypad` under Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm trying
to set the keys for the game `Xonotic`.

The keys work OK, except for the keys for mouse (touchpad).

I don't know which keys to map for:

> mouse vertical
>
> mouse vertical reverse
>
> mouse horizontal
>
> mouse horizontal reverse

These keys are used for aiming in the game `Xonotic`.

When I map a key to lets say "mouse vertical" it behaves that the mouse
is immediately up, and the character looks to the ceiling. But I want him to look only a little higher.

Do you know which axis/buttons to map to which mouse moves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xonotic has built-in gamepad support, no need to use a separate app like qjoypad.

To configure Xonotic for gamepad support you need to use the in-game console (there's no settings UI for it) by pressing Shift+Esc. From there you can set cvars to configure your gamepad bindings. The relevant cvars start with `joy_`:

https://xonotic.org/tools/cacs/#0a/0/joy

Other users have repoted that the default bindings are broken on Linux, try this:

```
joy_enable 1
joy_axisforward 1
joy_axispitch 4
joy_axisside 0
joy_axisup -1
joy_axisyaw 3
```

https://gitlab.com/xonotic/xonotic-data.pk3dir/issues/1947

If the bindings above aren't correct it's probably because your F310 doesn't use the same axis indices. `joy_axispitch 4` should be the Y axis on the right thumbstick, but depending on your gamepad axis 4 might be a trigger axis or might not be mapped at all. You can use `jstest /dev/input/js0` to see which inputs correspond to which axes. I think the bindings above are correct for an F310 in "X" mode.

Comment: Thank you, this opened my eyes, but I have still troubles. I pressed Shift+Esc and then I tried the commands joy_axisforward 1 etc. and then exited with the "exit" command. And now the joystick doesn't work at all. And in the xonotic settings, under input, "use joystick input" is checked but grayed out, so i can't change it.

Comment: When I try to set joy_active variable, it writes me that joy_active is read-only

Comment: Yeah, `joy_active` is meant to be read-only. It gets set to 1 once a gamepad is detected. I tried the above instructions and discovered you also need to set `joy_enable 1` to enable joystick input, there's also a "Use joystick input" option in the settings menu that sets the same cvar. Once I set `joy_enable 1` it printed a console message "Joystick 0 opened (SDL_Joystick 0 is "Microsoft X-Box 360 pad" with 6 axes, 11 buttons, 0 balls)". After that, I was able to configure inputs in the game's input settings menu.

Comment: There is one problem yet. The character goes backword without pressing anything. But I hope I will solve it.

Comment: Solved. There is a need to press the mode button, so it lights.

Comment: I'd like to set joy_axispitch 7 joy_axisyaw 6, but it's impossible. It's little unconfortable to shoot and aim with the same hand. Other useful thing to set is joy_sensitivitypitch 0.4